# Google Apps Script: как это работает? JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script

Я нашла готовое решение в интернете, но я очень хочу понять, как оно работает.

У меня есть гугл-форма, в которой регистрируются участники мероприятия. К ней привязана таблица. И есть скрипт, который отправляет мне на ящик "краткое содержание новой записи" при заполнении формы новым участником.
Краткое содержание делает вот такой кусок:

```
            var dataRange = responceSheet.getDataRange();
            var data = dataRange.getValues();
            var headers = data[0];
            for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
             var e = {};
             e.values = data[row];
             e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
             e.namedValues = {};
             for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
              e.namedValues[headers[col]] = [e.values[col]];
             }
            }
            var Responce="",
             data = e.namedValues;
            for(var headers in data){
             Responce+=headers+" : "+(data[headers]&&data[headers][0]?data[headers][0]:JSON.stringify(data[headers]))+"\r\n <br>";
            }
```

Для меня это выглядит не совсем понятно. Как именно это работает?

В форме не все поля обязательны - и если что-то не заполнено, то в "Responce" это выглядит как (например, для ФИО) ФИО: [""]. Это некрасиво (если использовать скрипт для отправки копии тому, кто заполнил форму).

Answer (score 1):

Все что находиться после двух наклонных полос (//комментарий ) и между вертикальной полоской со звездой (/* комментарий */), это пояснение к коду, эта часть кода не выполняется.

```
    // Создаем новые переменные и заносим туда какие-то значения
    var dataRange = responceSheet.getDataRange(); // В переменную dataRange заносим значение responceSheet.getDataRange(), responceSheet - мне неизвестно, но видимо это ссылка на таблицу (тут не весь код), а .getDataRange() получает ссылку на область с данными
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // .getValues() получает данные из dataRange, то есть получает данные из таблицы с данными
    var headers = data[0]; // В переменную headers записываем первый элемент массива, в вашем случае это видимо название столбцов 

    // То есть первые 3 строки кода вы получили ссылку на данные, сами данные и отдельно только первую строчку из таблицы в которой храниться названия столбцев


    // Это цикл, который перебирает поочередно все ваши данные из таблицы, кроме первой строки, в которой находятся названия столбцов
    for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
      var e = {}; // Создаете пустой объект в котором будем хранить данные в виде {ключ 1: значение 1, ключ 2: значение 2, ...}

      e.values = data[row]; // Добавляем в объект ключ "values" и заносим в него значение data[row]
      e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length); // Добавляем в объект ключ "range" и заносим в него значение dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length)
      e.namedValues = {}; // Добавляем в объект ключ "namedValues" с заносим в него пустой объект

      // Создаем еще один внутренний цикл, который поочередно перебирает названия столцев
      for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
        e.namedValues[headers[col]] = [e.values[col]]; // В e.namedValues создаем новый ключ с названием столбца и заносим в него данные, соответствующее данному столбцу и строке.
      }
    }

    // То есть код выше это своеобразное переделывание вида данных, их массива в объект


    var Responce = "", // Создаем новую переменную Responce и записываем в нее пустую строку
        data = e.namedValues; // Создаем новую переменную data и записываем в нее объект с данными ключ = название столбца, значение = значение этого столбца

    // Снова создаем цикл, теперь мы перебираем все пары {ключ:значение}
    for(var headers in data){
      // Заносим данные в Responce.
      // К старому значению Responce добавляем название столбца, ставим двоеточие, потом добавляем значение в этом столбце при соблюдение условия что такое название столбца существует, и переносим на новую строчку
      Responce += headers + " : " + (data[headers] && data[headers][0]?data[headers][0]:JSON.stringify(data[headers]))+"\r\n <br>";

      /* строку выше можно переписать в более понятной форме, например так:
         var key = ""; // В этой переменной храним значение из строки текущего столбца

         // Проверка,
         // data[headers] означает, если в data существует ключ headers то утверждение истина (true)
         // data[headers][0] означает, если в data существует ключ headers и в этом ключе есть данные то утверждение истина (true)
         // && означает что оба утверждения должны давать истину
         if (data[headers] && data[headers][0]) {
           // Выполним этот код если истина
           key = data[headers][0]; 
         } else {
           // Выполним этот код если лож
           key = JSON.stringify( data[headers] ); // JSON.stringify превращает любой текст или код в текстовую строку.
         }

         // Собираем строку
         Responce += headers + ": " + key + "\r\n <br>";
      */
    }
```

Это, конечно, не самое лучшее объяснение, ну хоть какое-то :)

Comment: А для кого предназначено первое предложение ответа? В вопросе вроде не спрашивается о том, как комментарии писать.

Comment: Автор вопроса говорит: "Я ничего не смыслю в программировании"

Comment: Но не на столько же. Вам нужно ответить на вопрос, а не учить автора азам.

Comment: Простите, я новичок на этом сервисе